# JNA Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function

Tags: java, jna

I'm learning JNI and JNA, and I'm facing the problem stated in the title while trying the examples of JNA

This is my pom and test code

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>5.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
public interface Clibrary extends Library {
    Clibrary INSTANCE = Native.load( "TestJNA", Clibrary.class);

    int hello();
    int basicTest(int a, float b, String pChar);
    void arrayTest(String pStr,  byte[] puStr);

    void pointerTest(IntByReference pInt, FloatByReference pFloat);

    void mallocTest(Memory pString);

    void doublePointTest(PointerByReference ppInt, PointerByReference ppStr);
    void freePt(Pointer pt);
}
```

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "E:\\javaProject\\xxxxxxxx\\jniLearn\\src\\main\\resources\\lib");
        Clibrary.INSTANCE.hello();
    }

}
```

`TestJNA.dll` is written and compiled by myself.Here is the class structure, using Visual Studio 2019.The platform is x64

[image]

Here is the full stack exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'hello': The specified program could not be found.
    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:252)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:620)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:596)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:582)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:248)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.hello(Unknown Source)
    at org.szh.jna.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

I tried to use the absolute path

```
Clibrary INSTANCE = Native.load("E:\\javaProject\\xxxxxxxx\\jniLearn\\src\\main\\resources\\libTestJNA",Library.class);
```

but the same problem still occurs.

---

this is TestJNA.cpp code.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "TestJNA.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/**
    No parameter test
*/
int hello()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}

/*
    Basic data type test
*/
int basicTest(int a, float b)
{
    printf("a=%d\n", a);
    printf("b=%f\n", b);
    return (int)(a + b);
}

/*
    Pointer and array tests
*/
void arrayTest(char* pStr, unsigned char* puStr)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("%s\n", pStr);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%c ", puStr[i]);
    }
}

/*
    Basic data type pointer test
*/
void pointerTest(int* pInt, float* pFloat)
{
    *pInt = 10;
    *pFloat = 12.34;
}

/*
    Dynamic memory test
*/
void mallocTest(char* pszStr)
{
    strcpy_s(pszStr, 50, "Happay Children's Day!");
}

/*
    secondary pointer
*/
void doublePointTest(int** ppInt, char** ppStr)
{
    printf("before int:%d\n", **ppInt);
    **ppInt = 10086;

    *ppStr = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy_s(*ppStr, 50, "Happy  National Day!");
}

/*
    freed
*/
void freePoint(void* pt) {
    if (pt != NULL) {
        free(pt);
    }
}

int main()
{
    hello();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IIRC, the naive approach for matching names like this only works for C functions, and C++ applies some form of name-mangling. You may want to check what https://github.com/nativelibs4java/JNAerator generates (though it hasn't been maintained for a long time).

Comment: It may help if you add the source of TestJNA.cpp

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks for the reply, the code of TestJNA.cpp has been added to this entry.